# Javascript Array URL Variables

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I just need a brief run down of the purpose of this function. As
far as I can tell, its looking for variables from the URL and passing them
into an Array Object, then returning that Array for further processing.

But I need more insight.

```
        function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting downvoted. I didn't write this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is taking a url string, slicing off the part before the ?, splitting is by `&` separators, and then making a dictionary of the `key=value` arguments in the URL

For example

`https://www.google.com/search?q=hello+siri&oq=hello+sir&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3327j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8`

In this google search url,

1. `https://www.google.com/search` would be sliced off,
2. `q=hello+siri&oq=hello+sir&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3327j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8` would be split by `&`.
3. You would get all the key value pairs in vars, like 'q':'hello+siri', etc.

Comment: Thanks Josh. That's I all i needed to know. :)